# What is the difference between a diffusion model and GANs?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks

Recently, I hear a lot of people claiming that diffusion models beat GANs, also providing less training time. I've searched about these two type of models, and I am confused, because somehow they both use gaussian loss to blur and then train to reconstruct the image. They also seem to use autoencoders in the process. Can someone please explain and elaborate in more detail about these two types of models?

Comment: Google :). 

See, example, this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbLgFrlTnGU&t=3s and https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/diffusion-models-for-machine-learning-introduction/ and ...